# Javascript - reset values back to 0 after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, button, reset

I'm creating an online grocery store that allows the user to add items to their cart and click a submit button when they're finished. Once the user clicks 'submit', I would like all the totals and items to be reset back to their initial value of 0. When I tried implementing this in the function submitted() however, it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
function showReceipt(){
    let userPicked = document.getElementById("list").value;
    var divTwo = document.getElementById("div2");
    let div = document.getElementById("counter");
    if(userPicked == 'storeOne'){
        tax = (total*0.13); 
        total = (subtotal + tax + parseFloat(storeOne.delivery_charge));
        var totals = "Subtotal: $" + subtotal.toFixed(2) + '<br>' + 'Tax: $' + tax.toFixed(2) + '<br>' + 'Delivery Fee: $' + storeOne.delivery_charge.toFixed(2) + '<br>' + "Total: $" + total.toFixed(2);
        totals += '<br>';
        totals += `<input type=button value="Submit" onclick="submitted(this)"/>`
        divTwo.innerHTML = totals;
    }

}

function submitted(submitted){
  console.clear();
  console.log(submitted.closest('div').textContent.trim());
  subtotal = 0;
  alert("Order complete");
}
```

Comment: Where does the `submitted()` function try to do this?

Comment: I added the button in the line `<input type=button value="Submit" onclick="submitted(this)"/>` and when I click it, an alert in the function submitted() pops up saying the order was successful. I assumed the reset would also go in the same function, but when I set subtotal = 0 it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is `subtotal` variable declared globally or in a closure that wraps the `if` statement and the `submitted` function?

Comment: Setting the variable doesn't change what's displayed in the form. You need to assign to `.value` of all the input fields.

Comment: `divTwo.innerHTML = ''` will remove the Subtotal line.

Comment: subtotal is a global variable